# Firefox CSS Cursor on a Button Image

Tags: html, css, firefox

So, I have a DIV full of four HTML buttons that use an image instead of any text. Using CSS, I style it so that the `img` is the same width as its parent `button`. On three of the four buttons, they will always carry the `cursor: pointer` attribute because they will always be clickable. The fourth button, however, will occasionally be in a state in which it is disabled, so I have to toggle the CSS between `cursor: pointer` and `cursor: default`.

As my code stands, this works properly in Chrome and IE 7/8/9 (6 is not in my supported audience), however Firefox does not change `cursor` from default for any of them, regardless of if one of the buttons are disabled. Note that while this does work when I apply the `cursor` attribute to the parent BUTTON element, I'd prefer to use CSS to have the cursor change rather than use any client-side Javascript. Since this works in two of the three modern browsers I'm testing (including IE7, mind you!), I thought it should be possible in FF too.

Here's the HTML markup that I have:

```
<button id="btn1" class="my-button"><img src="/path/to/my-img1.gif" alt="Img1" /></button>
<button id="btn2" class="my-button"><img src="/path/to/my-img2.gif" alt="Img2" /></button>
<button id="btn3" class="my-button"><img src="/path/to/my-img3.gif" alt="Img3" /></button>
<button id="btn4" class="my-button"><img src="/path/to/my-img4.gif" alt="Img4" /></button>
```

And here are the CSS classes that I have designated for this markup, as well:

```
<style>
    .my-button {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    vertical-align: top;
    border: none;
    background: none;
    }

    .my-button img {
    cursor: pointer;
    }

    .my-button img .disabled {
    cursor: default;
    }
</style>
```

And for anyone with any of that pesky curiosity, all of the click events and action is handled with jQuery depending on whatever business logic I need to go with it and the surrounding page.

If there's more information that I can furnish, please let me know. I feel like I came across a Firefox stumbling block here.

**Edit:** For reference, I'm using Firefox 4.0 with Firebug installed. Same behavior whether I have a Firebug on for that tab or not.  Chrome is up-to-date, currently at version 10.0.648.204.

**Edit 2:** As I've denoted in the comments below, I still have not figured out a solution to this issue, but have settled on using @wdm's answer as a temporary solution - this way Firefox gets `cursor: pointer` set for all buttons regardless of state, and Chrome and IE will obey the CSS I put forth for the embedded `img` in each `button` tag.  If I find out what's going on in my code or if someone else finds a proper solution for Firefox, I'll move the answer there. Thanks again for the suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried?

```
.my-button {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

EDIT: You could also make a separate class with "cursor:pointer" and use jQuery's .addClass() .removeClass() depending on the state. Or have jQuery directly alter the css with

```
.css("cursor", "pointer");
```

EDIT: One more idea...

```
button {
    cursor: pointer;
}
button:disabled {
    cursor: default;
}
```

Seems to be working for me in all major browsers.

Comment: I have tried this, and while it may be the temporary fix for me (`cursor: pointer` is displayed for ALL buttons regardless of state in Firefox, yet works correctly in Chrome and IE), this is essentially applying the cursor style to the parent BUTTON element. If possible I'd like to try to apply it to the children instead, but Firefox may prevent that.

Comment: I will select this as the correct answer because it's very close, but it unfortunately doesn't "fix" the issue for me in Firefox 4 - merely stubs in acceptable behavior until I can figure out what's going on here - whether it's Firefox's fault or interfering CSS on my own part.  I'll give anyone credit for the "correct" solution to this issue, or will update it if I find an error in my code.

Comment: Should have said it was FF4 earlier. It's so buggy right now I can't stand to use it.

Comment: sorry about that, I added that information in my first edit, but by then you must've already started in on your reply.  And in your second edit, the class `disabled` is actually placed on the child `img` element, not on the parent `button` element, but nonetheless.  Not sure if your first edit where you suggest using JQ to set the CSS via the client, but I'd prefer to stay away from any JS hacks to accomodate for this Firefox folly.

Answer (score 1):

**Two possible fixes:**

1 - Use `<input type="image" src="/path/to/my-img1.gif">` instead of nesting `<img>` in `<button>`

2 - Use `.mybutton:hover { cursor: pointer; }` for the CSS.

Comment: Unfortunately, neither of these solutions work:
1 - Not only does changing this tag to `input` break my layout for other reasons (whether this is code smell at this point or not is somewhat inconsequential to me ATM), it also does not fix the cursor issue
2 - Same as above yet the layout remains intact. For some reason Firefox refuses to accept the child of a button element defining the cursor on a hover, yet Chrome and IE are both happy to oblige.

Comment: @Mattygabe: `<input type="image">` and `button:hover { cursor: pointer; }` both work for me in FireFox 3.6.x. I'd wager that you have some other CSS that may be interfering.

Comment: That very well may be the case with the CSS interfering elsewhere.  I'd suspect that changes from 3.6 to 4.0 wouldn't break this behavior, but that's just a hunch. Interesting.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that .disabled is a class, not a pseudo-class. It matches any `<button class="disabled...`

If you want to select every disabled button, you have to use the :disabled pseudo-class, which automatically selects all the buttons in the disabled state.

I believe that the correct version of your code would be as follows, though I cannot check it at this time:

```
.my-button :disabled img {
    cursor: default;
}
```

The pseudo-class is defined by the w3c here: http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/CR-css3-selectors-20011113/#UIstates

They have a demo of it: http://www.w3.org/Style/CSS/Test/CSS3/Selectors/current/html/full/flat/css3-modsel-24.html

Comment: Unfortunately, the pseudo class  does not work and actually breaks the setting of the default cursor in Chrome and IE (so `cursor: pointer` is set regardless of state, and Firefox still has `cursor: default` regardless of state)